# How to set a slider's value to a variable

Tags: c++, windows, xaml

Hey guys I am pretty lost on how to get the data from a slider into a variable. Everyone seems to be using a textblock to read the data but i want to store the slider's number into a double variable. Anyone know how i can go about doing this? Thanks.

Comment: This is WPF, I assume?

Comment: Yeah sorry forgot to say that

Answer (score 0):

You can access the slider object from the sender. Accessing `Value()` should give you a double. Example:

```
private void Slider_ValueChanged(object sender,
    RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs<double> e)
{
    // ... Get Slider reference.
    var slider = sender as Slider;
    // ... Get Value.
    double value = slider.Value;
}
```

Found this at http://www.dotnetperls.com/slider

I hope this helps!